# Transform a <string, List<string>> map to change values to be as keys

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I have a following map, which contains basket number to list of fruits in that basket.

```
val basketMap = mapOf("basket1" to listOf("apples", "oranges", "grapes"),
                      "basket2" to listOf("oranges", "kiwi", "pineapple"),
                      "basket3" to listOf("grapes", "apples", "strawberry"))
```

I want to convert this map to fruit to list of baskets that fruit is present in
Ex:

```
val finalExpectedResult = mapOf("apples" to listOf("basket1", "basket3"),
                                "oranges" to listOf("basket1", "basket2"),
                                "grapes" to listOf("basket1", "basket3"),
                                "kiwi" to listOf("basket2"),
                                "pineapple" to listOf("basket2")
                                "strawberry" to listOf("basket3"))
```

How do I achieve the `finalExpectedResult` map from the above `basketMap` in kotlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, flatten the map into a list of pairs `(basket, fruit)`, then group again:

```kotlin
basketMap.flatMap { (k, v) -> v.map { k to it } }
    .groupBy({ it.second }, { it.first })
```

If our collections are big, we can use sequences instead:

```kotlin
basketMap.asSequence()
    .flatMap { (k, v) -> v.asSequence().map { k to it } }
    .groupBy({ it.second }, { it.first })
```

This way we avoid creating a huge list of items and instead, we build a map while iterating over the source map.

Answer (score 0):

```
val finalExpectedResult = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()

basketMap.forEach { (basket, fruits) -> 
    fruits.forEach { fruit -> //forEach fruit in all the entries
        if (finalExpectedResult[fruit] == null) { //Checks if it's not present as a key in the new map
            finalExpectedResult[fruit] = mutableListOf(basket) //If it's not present, it gets added as a key
        } else {
            finalExpectedResult[fruit]?.add(basket) //Otherwise the basket is added to the list of values of that key
        }
    }
}
```

This should do the trick!

It adds a fruit as a key if not present, otherwise, it adds the basket which contains it to the value list.

If you need the map to be immutable just call `finalExpectedResult.toMap()` and assign it accordingly.